# how to convert two dimensional byte array into a single dimensional byte array

Tags: c#

```
byte[][] s1_byte
static byte[][] ToBytes(string[] ascii)
{
    byte[][] results = ascii.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x)).ToArray();
    return results;
}
```

I want to convert this.

how to convert two dimensional byte array into a single dimensional byte array

Comment: Wording is pretty vague, how are you looking to combine them? Row by row? Column by column?

Answer (score 3):

quick change would be using `SelectMany`

```
static byte[] ToBytes(string[] ascii)
{
    // use `SelectMany`
    byte[] results = ascii.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(x => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x)).ToArray();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `AsEnumerable` and you get cleaner code. It's not needed there.